# Cannot find protocol declaration for "XXXX"

Tags: objective-c, delegation

I am stuck with this problem. I have the following .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MapSettingsViewDelegate

- (void)settingsDidUpdate:(BOOL)scheme;

@end

@interface MapSettingsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MapSettingsViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *titleItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView;

- (id)init;
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

When I declare the following:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MapSettingsViewDelegate>
```

The compiler complains with the following message:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MapSettingsViewDelegate'
```

I have the same kind of delegate declaration in other files in the same project that are compiled without a glitch. I spent the last four hours trying to figuring out what I am doing wrong. Cleaning the project does not nothing.

Comment: Did you import the .h?

Comment: @Eduardo Mauro,I'm trying to help you, Could you please tell me all the #import's in MapViewController.h and MapSettingsViewController.h file

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama all includes of MapSettingsViewController are above. Just UIKit. In MapViewController are included those headers:  <UIKit/UIKit.h> <MapKit/MapKit.h> <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
"MapSettingsViewController.h" "PlacemarkSelectionViewController.h"
"PopoverView.h"

Comment: Another information: even if I include a syntax error in MavSettingsViewController, XCode keep complaining with the same error message. The corresponding .m file is not compiled.

Comment: Show us the actual imports. I've got a shiny $1 bill that says they're circular.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, pointed in the correct direction. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. [As suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379822/finding-a-circular-reference?rq=1), I created a new class with a different name and copied all coded from the previous class. Worked flawlessly. It seems XCode lost track of something.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into preprocessor problems. Both of your classes import each other. I think you can solve this by adding @class below your protocol declaration as shown below; and moving your #import "mapViewController.h" line into MapSettingsViewController.m file. The @class tells the compiler that you will include the class content somewhere else (in the .m file).

Note that, on the top of your MapViewController.h class file you can include #import "MapSettingsViewController.h" just like normal. Hope this help. I ran into the same problem myself earlier.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MapSettingsViewDelegate

- (void)settingsDidUpdate:(BOOL)scheme;

@end

@class MapViewController 

@interface MapSettingsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MapSettingsViewDelegate> delegate;
...
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Import the MapSettingsViewController.h file